# PHP read string and if it contains a certain string put the string near the other string.. [Hard to explain]

Tags: php, string

I've currently got a list of dynamic strings. So lets say I've got this string here : (in this case I was lucky that the a values were near eachother but it's not always the case.

```
a14,2T,50,33.26:a14,3T,50,33.26,a14,4,50,33.26,
a17,2T,50,33.26:a17,3T,50,33.26,a17,4,50,33.26,
a4,2T,50,33.26:a4,3T,48,33.26,a4,4,49,33.26,
a3,2T,50,33.26:a3,3T,47,33.26,a3,4,48,33.26,
a9,2T,50,33.26:a9,3T,50,33.26,a9,4,50,33.26,
a2,2T,50,31.48:a2,3T,50,33.26,a2,4,50,33.26,
a12,2T,50,33.26:a12,3T,49,33.26,a12,4,49,33.26,
a10,2T,50,33.26:a10,3T,50,33.26,a10,4,50,33.26,
a11,2T,50,31.48:a11,3T,50,33.26,a11,4,50,33.26,
a8,2T,50,33.26:a8,3T,50,33.26,a8,4,49,33.26,
a16,2T,50,33.26:a16,3T,50,33.26,a16,4,50,33.26,
a6,2T,50,33.26:a6,3T,50,33.26,a6,4,49,33.26,
a13,2T,50,33.26:a13,3T,49,33.26,a13,4,50,33.26,
a5,2T,50,31.48:a5,3T,50,33.26,a5,4,50,33.26,
a15,2T,50,31.48:a15,3T,50,33.26,a15,4,50,33.26,
a7,2T,50,33.26:a7,3T,50,33.26,a7,4,50,33.26,
a1,2T,50,33.26:a1,3T,45,33.26,a1,4,48,33.26,
```

I want the string to be :

```
a1,a1,a1,a3,a7,a9,a5,a5,a6,a8,a0,a2
```

The order doesn't really matter but **I want the ones which are for example a1 to be near eachothe**r, any idea how I can do this.. I have no idea on how to google it also I tried.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: The string is dynamic

Comment: So in the first string is each line terninated by a NewLine?

Comment: Is that string in a file of a variable?

Comment: No uhmm, I'll edit in a proper list of the strings @RiggsFolly added :) so for all I know it could be a14, a12, a10 etc.. but in this case i was lucky they were near eachother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go! Change the string to an array, then sort it, and convert back!

```
<?php

$string = 'a1
a3
a7
a9
a5
a6
a1
a8
a0
a2
a5';

$array = explode("\n", $string);
sort($array);
$string = implode(',',$array);
echo $string;
```

Which outputs:

```
a0,a1,a1,a2,a3,a5,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9
```

Check it out here: https://3v4l.org/rIQ1e